# Dystopian short story by Walter Jon Williams about AI and human disaffection

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is probably late 1990s early 2000s by Walter Jon Williams.  Short story, easy to remember, aside from me not knowing the title.

- AIs, along with the top 2% of *smartest* people, basically run everything and provide for everything.  People aren't really in need or oppressed, but they don't have much to do.  This isn't gone into in any detail, it's quite a short story.
- The protagonist, a near genius, and his anarchist friends have found, IIRC, some kind of enzyme or viral computer code that is going to "knock out the AIs".
- They launch their revolution and... nothing much happens.  The AIs immediately counteract it and the big attack is shut down within 5 minutes or so.  Nothing really happens, no police comes a-knockin', they're ignored.  It concludes with the protagonist recognizing that they never had a chance to start with and are insignificant.

I looked at Walter Jon Williams' page on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Jon_Williams) and [FictionDb](https://www.fictiondb.com/author/walter-jon-williams%7E38151.htm), searched for his short stories, "AI 2% dinosaurs".  None struck me as a match.  "Dinosaurs" looked like it might be, but it's unrelated.

It's also funny in that it was specifically 2% and predated the entry into the vernacular about the top 1% that we are now familiar with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the story "[Flatline](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42447)" from WJW's collection [*Facets*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36825).

The story concerns an attack by the protagonist's friend Lewis on the matte-black octahedron of "Neurodyne Intelgene A.G." using a tailored virus that, injected into the AI, causes a 20-minute outage.  (The octahedron is described as standing on a point, maintained by constant adjustment by the AI.)

The narrator is initially fearful for his friend, but comes to the realization that the AI (collectively; this one and others like it) permit, and may even subtly encourage, such people as a way of constantly testing and improving their defences.  In the end he goes into that line as well, basically for something to do.